# Javascript not always returning false

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code I have. The console always reads wrong. What is happening. I think it is when I objectofy the textbox.

```js
function compare() {
  var test = "test";
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var inputLen = input.length;
  var tick;
  for (tick = 0; tick < inputLen; tick++) {
    if (input[tick] != test[tick]) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if ((tick - 1) == test.length) {
    console.log("equal");
  } else {
    console.log("wrong");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="text">
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="compare()">
```

I really could use some help. The console.log always returns "wrong".

Comment: It should be `tick === test.length` (because `tick` increments one last time before the loop exits)

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? It seems you're testing whether two string values are equal by comparing them one letter at a time, but why wouldn't you just test `input == test`? Using the loop and not checking the lengths means an input of `"testing"` would be considered equal to your `"test"` value.

Comment: i didn't know you could compare them like that

Comment: @nnnnnn i tried your solution and it still did not work

Comment: If you just want to test whether two strings are equal, you simply say `if (test == input) { console.log("equal") } else { console.log("wrong") }`. No loop. There really isn't any more to it than that unless you want to do a case-insensitive comparison, and then you just do `if (test == input.toLowerCase())` (noting that `test` is already lowercase).

Comment: @user3851290 It works, edit your question, replace `(tick - 1)` with `tick` and run the code again.

Comment: @user3851290 `for(i=0;i<3;i++);console.log(i);` prints 3.

Answer (score 1):

While performing your `for` loop, the `tick` variable increases to 5 on the last iteration before exiting the loop. To resolve this, compare it to `test.length` without decreasing it with `-1`:

```js
function compare() {
  var test = "test";
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var inputLen = input.length;
  var tick;
  for (tick = 0; tick < inputLen; tick++) {
    if (input[tick] != test[tick]) {
      break;
    }
  }
  // After exiting the loop, tick will be equal to 5, not 4.
  if (tick === test.length) {
    console.log("equal");
  } else {
    console.log("wrong");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="text">
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="compare();">
```

Answer (score -3):

Solution 1

```
var test = "test";
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
var inputLen = input.length;
var tick;

for (tick=0; tick < inputLen; tick++)
{
    if (input[tick]!=test[tick])
    {
        break;
    }          
}

if (tick==test.length)
{
   console.log("equal");
}
else
{
   console.log("wrong");
}
```

Solution 2

```
var test = "test";
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
var inputLen = input.length;
var tick;

for (tick=1; tick <= inputLen; tick++)
{
   if (input[tick-1]!=test[tick-1])
   {
       break;
   }          
}

if ((tick - 1)==test.length)
{
   console.log("equal");
}
else
{
   console.log("wrong");
}
```